# Attempted Relative Import from Unknown Parent Package

Tags: python, python-packaging

I've been trying to import a sub-package from a main package from another sub-package in a quite different folder hierarchy.
It's specifically from a file "predict.py" under web/flask trying to import gvtools under greenvision/
I've tried the following methods:

```
from ...greenvision.gvtools import *
from ...greenvision import gvtools
import gvapps.greenvision.gvtools
from gvapps.greenvision.gvtools import *
from gvapps.greenvision import gvtools
```

All of them give the error described in the title or "no module named gvapps". I'm not sure this package structure works. What could be the issue?

[image: All folders contain init.py as you see.]

Comment: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/python_imports.html

Comment: You're correct. Turns out I don't know much about packages still.
Going deeper into another link I found, I was able to clarify myself more aswell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time
In summary, it's literally that, since I ran this script with `python predict.py` it thought itself as __main__, which can't be considered inside a package, therefore I had to do `python -m gvapps.greenvision.predict` to run the file as a module and recognize itself as a package related to other packages.